Incorrect Date Range in Facebook Graph API Insights Response
I'm encountering an issue with the Facebook Graph API where the responses do not respect the specified date ranges in my queries. Here are the details of my requests and the responses I receive:
Query using time_range:
/campaigns?level=campaign&fields=account_id,effective_status,id,name,insights{reach,dda_results,frequency,cost_per_conversion,spend,impressions,cpm,clicks,cost_per_unique_click,purchase_roas,actions,action_values},lifetime_budget,start_time&limit=1&time_increment=1&time_range={'since':'2024-09-07','until':'2024-09-08'}

Response:
"insights": {
    "reach": "372827",
    "date_start": "2024-08-12",
    "date_stop": "2024-09-10"
}

Query using date_preset=yesterday:
/campaigns?date_preset=yesterday&level=campaign&fields=account_id,effective_status,id,name,insights{reach,dda_results,frequency,cost_per_conversion,spend,impressions,cpm,clicks,cost_per_unique_click,purchase_roas,actions,action_values},lifetime_budget,start_time&limit=1&time_increment=1

Response:
"insights": {
    "reach": "372827",
    "date_start": "2024-08-12",
    "date_stop": "2024-09-10"
}

Despite specifying narrow date ranges, the API returns data spanning almost a month. Has anyone else faced this issue, or can provide insights on how to enforce the specified date range in the query?

The way you are currently passing time_range, it would apply to the campaigns themselves, I think. If you want to apply it to insights, you'd need to somehow "connect" it to that specifically - but I couldn't tell you, which exact syntax to use in that case. Maybe the field expansion guide can help to figure it out, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/field-expansion/
